# can I add import when editing method body code template in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, code-templates

I am trying to edit the template of creating a new method. I want to do something like this:

```
throw new mypackage.UnimplementedException();
```

but I want to add my package to imports and not to declare it with full package on the method body. I tried using:

```
 ${:import(mypackage.UnimplementedException)}
```

but it doesn't work (works only in editor templates)

Comment: I think you've answered your own question: `it doesn't work (works only in editor templates)` (unfortunately)

Comment: Is there a request for eclipse about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a request for this:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333313